# ng-class on the angular material chips

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material, md-chip

I want to create some backlight for the chips which have an 'active' flag based on my key value type for which I have made a `ng-class="{activeTag: $chip.active}"` but it doesn't works. How to add this ng-class on dynamically created md-chip.

**View**

```
<md-chips class="custom-chips selected" ng-model="tags" ng-class="{activeTag: $chip.active}" readonly="true">
  <md-chip-template style="cursor: pointer;" >
    <a ui-sref="">
      <strong>{{$chip.id}}</strong>
      <em>({{$chip.name}})</em>
    </a>
  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

**Controller**

```
controller('ChipsController', function($scope) {
    $scope.tags = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Pop',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Rock',
        active: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Reggie',
        active: false
      }
  ];

});
```

**css**

```
.activeTag md-chip{
  background: rgba(85, 107, 47, 0.66) !important;
  color: white !important; 
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2lyKZtIadvuCkYF6S865?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely the fact that you're trying to use `$chip` on the `md-chips` element. This is the **container** *not* the **repeater**. The content inside your **template** is what gets repeated.

I'm not too familiar with the MD components, but you're a level or two too far outside to access `$chip`

Comment: Thank you @Atticus, you're right. I need to find another way to implement this class to md-chip but it's another question

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. modify tour css to just .activetag and add ng-class to md-chip-template

CSS:

```
.activeTag {
  background: rgba(85, 107, 47, 0.66) !important;
  color: white !important; 
}
```

html :

```
<md-chips class="custom-chips selected" ng-model="tags" readonly="true">
  <md-chip-template ng-class="{activeTag: $chip.active}" style="cursor: pointer;" >
    <a ui-sref="">
      <strong>{{$chip.id}}</strong>
      <em>({{$chip.name}})</em>
    </a>
  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

Comment: In this case we'll have this class only in `md-chip-template`. Visually it's not what i want, i need backlight for everything in tag